# Programmatically press button or anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to web programming. In html web page I want to press a button or anchor tag programmatically.

jquery api has [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function which triggers call back function attached to a event,   but  my requirement is to programmatically press a button or link.

Comment: You want to learn Javascript first (jQuery is a Javascript library). You're looking for events, specifically `onclick` (or `$.click()` in it's jQuery shorthand form).

Comment: @JaredFarrish, that is not triggering a click, it's setting the event handler called when an element is clicked.

Comment: @Kiyura - `$.click()` calls the event.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Oh, I suppose I misunderstood. However, it may help to clarify what you mean. The same function is normally used to set the event handler.

Comment: @Kiyura - http://jsfiddle.net/zRSwf/ That's why it's called a shorthand method. You can also use `$.on` and `$.bind`, although the latter and some others have been deprecated I believe.

Comment: @JaredFarrish .click(); function don't press button its just attached handler to function can u give a sample code for wat you said?, thanks

Comment: `$('#anchorID').click();` effectively "clicks" the button programatically. As answered by @11684 ten minutes ago ?

Comment: The fiddle demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/zRSwf/1/ jQuery uses method signatures to determine what to do when called, so `$.click()` with no arguments *calls* the `onclick`.

Comment: The `$.trigger()` call would be [`$.trigger('click')`](http://jsfiddle.net/zRSwf/2/). Note, no `on` syntax is used in jQuery.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for example but your code also just triggers the handler I want to simulate click function programmatically, is it possible that browser feel that button has been pressed

Comment: @user1870773, If you want to simulate the click event then you have to have a registered handler for that element and without the handler you can't take any action.

Comment: I don't want to call onclick function I want to click an element programmatically

Comment: @user1870773, you want to click an element programmatically and then what action do you want to take for that click event ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera actually I just want to click on particular element on page load...

Comment: If you're trying to simulate a human-origin click (as in a System IO "real mouse click"), that's not possible in a regular browser environment.

Comment: @JaredFarrish actually trying for html5 video auto play function in android browser but it requires me to click the media player screen on page load (android browser dont support autoplay)so I look for way to simulate mouse click on page load

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't ask the real question that's in the above comment, so you didn't get the answer you needed. My suggestion, delete this question and ask *that* (above) question instead, without all of these false starts. Always provide what your problem is, not just what you *think* you need.

Comment: ok i delete this question and ask other

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trigger a click on a button or link, the better way to accomplish what you want to do is usually by visiting the link by setting [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location), or by calling the function or submitting the form that the button click would result in.

Answer (score 1):

I see you use jQuery.

```
$("#myElement").click();
```

Should so the trick.